# This is a street on which many famous churches are

Tags: adjectives, clauses

Is the sentence in the title correct?
I had to join the sentences below into one using adjective clauses.

> This is a street. Many famous churches are on it.

Traditional English: This is a street on which many famous churches are.

Modern English: This is a street which many famous churches are on.

Are they both correct?

Comment: Who says the second sentence is a modern English? Where did you get those sentences?

Comment: It's from a TOEFL grammar book. The examples given were: "That is the street. I live on that street." -> "That is the street on which I live." It was suggested that this is the traditional form while the modern English form is "That is the street which I live on."

Comment: Then, did you write the sentence "This is a street. Many famous churches are on it." yourself?

Comment: I believe all of the sentences are technically correct; however, I think the way to say it would be something like *This is a street on which many famous churches stand.*

Answer (score 1):

You might consider saying

"Many famous churches line this street."

or

"This street is lined with many famous churches."

[**line [verb]**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/line)

> > Stand or be positioned at intervals along: ‘a processional route lined by people waving flags’

Answer (score -1):

Try not to end a sentence with a preposition (in this case, the preposition is 'on).

I think the best option is probably: "This is a street which has many famous churches on it."

Comment: Or even just "This is a street which has many famous churches"  - people can assume that the churches are **on** the street, rather than above it or below it for example.

Comment: Your suggestion is wrong.

Comment: @Rathony who is that addressed to?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I would have used your user name if it was directed to you. I don't think "This is a street which has many famous churches on it" is the grammatically right sentence.

Comment: @Rathony does that rule apply to the person who it **was** addressed to, or solely to me?

Comment: @MaxWilliams None of my comments were addressed to you except for the first sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: @Rathony That's a rather terse comment without any justification - would you care to explain why you feel my response is wrong/ungrammatical?

Comment: Never try not to end a sentence with a preposition. It will just make your writing clumsy.

Comment: That's terrible advice. Ending with a preposition sounds a lot worse than the above. Of course you can do it ("What's the test on?") but in situations like the above, it's clear which sounds more clumsy. Which sounds worse? "Where's my coat?" vs. "Where's my coat to?" Granted, I'm from a place where the latter is very common and well understood, but I still wouldn't say avoiding it actively makes your writing more clumsy.